# Non modal dialog angular 8

Tags: angular, dialog, popup, angular-cli

I have a button in my angular app and I want the button to open a popup window.
The problem is that when the window opens the parent component is disabled until I close the window.
Is there any way to change it and make the popup window non-modal?

Also, I can't relocate and move the window on the screen.
Is it possible to make it movable?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use any components library like Angular Material?

Comment: You can try out popover. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples

Comment: @YaakovHatam No

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot thanks! but I want the window to be a separate *movable* window

Comment: you can create a simple mat-card and give it a z-index bigger than your body it will open like a modal add drag and drop to it and it will do the role of Non-Modal

Comment: @Natalie Did you happen to find a solution to this problem?